# In Reincarnated as a Slime, what are the approximate distances between locations, aka the scale of the map?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Below is a map of the world in which Reincarnated as a Slime happens but there isn't any indication of the scale of the map. Are there any indications of distances between locations with which estimates could be derived? For example, could one estimate distances based on the time it took Rimuru to get to Dwargon?

[image]

Comment: In Episode 4, it's said that it takes a goblin roughly two months to take the trip from their village to Dwargon. However, the dire wolves that evolved into Tempest wolves make the trip in 3 days. As for the path, it only says they follow the Ameld river north. Naturally this doesn't tell us how straight the path is, how fast average goblins can travel, or how fast Tempest wolves can travel.

Comment: The novel said that the direwolves ran at 50mph and went for half a day. without slowing or stopping. If 6 hours per day, then 900 miles for 3 days. It said that the path from the goblin village to Dwargon went straight north, albeit up and down mountains.

Comment: In the 4th novel, after they'd already started building the road, it said said that from Rimuru city to Dwargon was a little over 600 miles

Answer (score 0):

This might not be approximate but I'll mention it anyways. Before rimuru tempest showed up it might have taken them the time stamp of:

1. Dwargon - 2 Months
2. Beast Nation - 5 Months
3. Demon Lord Milim's Place - Fastest pace - 8-9 Months Slowest Pace - 11 Months
4. Holy Reuben Empire - Fastest pace - 10 Months Slowest Pace - 12-13 Months
5. Kingdom of Ingrasia - Fastest pace - 7 Months Slowest Pace - 9 Months
6. Barren Lands - Fastest pace - 13 Months Slowest Pace - 15 Months

Again this is not approximate but hope it eases the minds.

Comment: What's this based on? If Dwargon is based on goblin travel before evolving, they were probably slower than humans. Is that the measure for all distances?

Comment: @DavidHobs Yes, these might not be accurate since we haven't been exposed of any secret passageways in the anime so these might help based on they're expedition to dwargon